# Is the cloud save game created using unity and google play games plugin removed when uninstalling an app?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

This is my first time asking a question here since I can't find any confirmation if the cloud save game is deleted/removed when uninstalling an app.  I can definitely save the game and retrieve it but when I uninstall the app there is no save game retrieved.

What I'm trying to do is consolidate my local saved games to the cloud saved game then save the consolidated data locally and on the cloud.

I'm using Unity 5.6.0 and Google Play Games plugin 0.9.38.

I hope someone can confirm this or point me in the right direction on where I can find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that should work. No data is removed when you uninstall an app.

Comment: How are you retrieving it when the app is already uninstalled?

Comment: Thanks @JeanLuc! That means there's something wrong with my code. Thanks again!

Comment: @noogui after reinstalling. sorry for the confusion.